# How to change every program in a JDK to default

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have done update-alternatives with java:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

But javac still says:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.9.0-ea
```

because I use Java 9 for stuff. How do I change everything at once?

I am not good at shell, so a script that looks through all of the files in the `bin` and uses update alternatives on them would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now in the `webupd8` repository an `oracle-java_-setdefault` package, which you can use. And it works much better than the script.

See [`ppa:webupd8team/java`](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)